# Error 13 in Java Eclipse, how do I fix this?

Tags: java, eclipse, usb-drive

I just built a new PC and I tried to run eclipse on it from a USB stick, I did this earlier on my previous machine and it worked just as intended but after I upgraded my PC it gives me the error 13. I tried reinstalling java, jdk everything and it just doesn't want to work.

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.500.v20170531-1133
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
-showsplash
org.eclipse.epp.package.common
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs

-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_271\bin\javaw.exe


-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
```

this is my eclipse.ini file

Here is what comes up whenever I try to launch eclipse

[image]

Comment: Post the complete error message.

Comment: That looks like a 32 bit Eclipse (version 4.7) and a 64 bit Java. They must both be 32 bit or both 64 bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to run Eclipse from the USB drive, follow the steps given below:

1. Download JDK and install it in the USB drive.
2. Download Eclipse and extract it on the USB drive.

Make sure that both of them are 64-bit versions. It can still work if both of them are 32-bit version but I recommend you go for the 64-bit version. In any case, they should not be of mixed versions (i.e. one is 32-bit while the other one is 64-bit).

3. On the command prompt, change the directory to the USB drive and append the path to the JDK bin folder to the path variable e.g. `set path=%PATH%;path-to-jdk-bin-folder-in-USB`. Then use the command `java -version` to confirm if the correct Java version is picked up.
4. Change the directory to Eclipse folder and execute the command, `eclipse`.

Comment: Yup this did that, but another error came up. Will update the question and provide a screenshot.

Comment: Great! Feel free to comment in case you face any further issue/doubt.

Comment: Yeah just added the image of the new error :/

Comment: Nevermind, just fixed it!! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

That's usually indicative of a broken java version. Did you install java on the stick too? Your new PC is 64-bit, your old one was 32-bit, you have a 32-bit java; that's not going to work, install a modern 64-bit one from e.g. adoptopenjdk.net.

Alternatively, the problem is that you have no java installed at all; same fix: Install one.

NB: I'm taking a wild stab here, you haven't provided a ton of information.

Comment: I installed java from the java website and it said it was a 64 bit version

Comment: @Kac Make sure of it. You can do it with `java -version` and `javac -version`. Also which version of Eclipse are you using?

Comment: @Pshemo `org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356` makes it Eclipse 4.7 and it is 32 bit

Comment: I just installed the java from adoptopenjdk.net just as told and still the same error. So should I just install a 32 bit java version?

Comment: No, install a newer eclipse, a mid 2016 version? That's.. just... no.

Comment: Ideally move to Eclipse 2020-09 but that requires at least Java 11 (64 bit)

Comment: Would there be no other way of making the current version work? I have most of my programming stuff on the projects there and wouldn't want to lose it all.

Comment: A 32 bit Java 8 should work